# Automatically distribute lvm (stripes) for specific LVM2 VG on Linux

Tags: linux, lvm, openstack, diskmanagement

With Linux lvm2 I can create logical volumes inside a VG. When I specify with the `lvcreate` command striping/stripesize I can manually distribute the logical volumes over all physical volumes (as shown for *lvnova* below).

Is there a way to configure that lvcreate will always stripe and especially that if I create new LVs that they should be created round robin on the devices? (i.e. without specifying a physical "start" device in each lvcreate)

I need this to be configured persistently for a volume group which is used by OpenStack Nova for ephemeral devices. It looks like I cannot configure the lvm driver to actually distribute them more evenly.

I was looking for a way to specify it as attributes on the VG (since lvcreate is talking about inheriting allocations), but I cant find it in the manual.

The LVs have allocation policy inherit and the VG tells me it is normal:

```
# vgchange vgdata --alloc normal
Volume group allocation policy is already normal
```

I was also looking if there is a allocation policy inside lvm.conf. But there are only parameters for the cling2 strategy which does especially keep segments close together when extending a volume (which is not my main concern here).

Sample for a manually striped LV and for a OpenStack generated one volumes on a 4 physical volume system:

```
nvme0n1                                                               259:0    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1                                                           259:4    0   1.5T  0 part
  ├─vgdata-lvnova (dm-0)                                              252:0    0   750G  0 lvm  /srv/data
  ├─vgdata-ec3d1f0d--76f2--4cb2--af66--665dba0582b1_disk (dm-3)       252:3    0    50G  0 lvm
  ├─vgdata-ec3d1f0d--76f2--4cb2--af66--665dba0582b1_disk.swap (dm-4)  252:4    0     8G  0 lvm
  ├─vgdata-290ef35d--6d84--49cf--8d7d--3240dcd84a3e_disk (dm-5)       252:5    0    20G  0 lvm
 ...
nvme1n1                                                               259:1    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1                                                           259:5    0   1.5T  0 part
  └─vgdata-lvnova (dm-0)                                              252:0    0   750G  0 lvm  /srv/data
nvme2n1                                                               259:2    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme2n1p1                                                           259:6    0   1.5T  0 part
  └─vgdata-lvnova (dm-0)                                              252:0    0   750G  0 lvm  /srv/data
nvme3n1                                                               259:3    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme3n1p1                                                           259:7    0   1.5T  0 part
  └─vgdata-lvnova (dm-0)                                              252:0    0   750G  0 lvm  /srv/data

root@compute18:~# lvs --segments
  LV                                             VG     Attr      #Str Type    SSize
  lv-root                                        vg0    -wi-ao---    1 linear  223.52g
  lv-swap                                        vg0    -wi-ao---    1 linear   46.56g
  17bad6e1-41f0-4725-a74d-7a1f1df5f0b6_disk      vgdata -wi-ao---    1 linear   20.00g
  17bad6e1-41f0-4725-a74d-7a1f1df5f0b6_disk.swap vgdata -wi-ao---    1 linear    1.00g
  189585e0-9b69-4d7c-b1b4-194156312553_disk      vgdata -wi-ao---    1 linear   20.00g
...
  lvnova                                         vgdata -wi-ao---    4 striped 750.00g
```

BTW: I used a striped /dev/md0 before but I was hoping to get rid of this indirection.

<sub>This is Linux 4.4.0 on Ubuntu Trusty (lvm 2.0.2.98(2)) with KVM/nova OS Liberty.</sub>

Comment: I also asked the question on linux-lvm mailing list now since I feel at least the round robin sequence for striped segments makes sense: https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2017-May/msg00012.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `allocation/raid_stripe_all_devices=1` option in `lvm.config` mentioned by Andreas is only available with *Ubuntu Zesty*, and even then it seems to not turn on striped volumes by default.

For this reason we patched OS:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/storage/lvm.py
  else:
    check_size(vg, lv, size)
-   cmd = ('lvcreate', '-L', '%db' % size, '-n', lv, vg)
+   cmd = ('lvcreate', '-i', '4','-L', '%db' % size, '-n', lv, vg)
```

This does it for our case:

```
nvme0n1                                                              259:0    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1                                                          259:4    0   1.5T  0 part
  ├─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk (dm-5)      252:5    0   100G  0 lvm
  └─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk.swap (dm-6) 252:6    0     8G  0 lvm
nvme1n1                                                              259:1    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme1n1p1                                                          259:5    0   1.5T  0 part
  ├─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk (dm-5)      252:5    0   100G  0 lvm
  └─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk.swap (dm-6) 252:6    0     8G  0 lvm
nvme2n1                                                              259:2    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme2n1p1                                                          259:6    0   750G  0 lvm  /srv/data
  ├─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk (dm-5)      252:5    0   100G  0 lvm
  └─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk.swap (dm-6) 252:6    0     8G  0 lvm
nvme3n1                                                              259:3    0   1.5T  0 disk
└─nvme3n1p1                                                          259:7    0   1.5T  0 part
  ├─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk (dm-5)      252:5    0   100G  0 lvm
  └─vgdata-b063d1b9--e1ac--4cab--98d8--9a2d1c71406e_disk.swap (dm-6) 252:6    0     8G  0 lvm

# lvs --segments
  b063d1b9-e1ac-4cab-98d8-9a2d1c71406e_disk      vgdata -wi-ao---    4 striped 100.00g
  b063d1b9-e1ac-4cab-98d8-9a2d1c71406e_disk.swap vgdata -wi-ao---    4 striped   8.00g
```

We will open an OpenStack bug for this missing setting.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure this in `/etc/lvm.conf`.
If you set `raid_stripe_all_devices=1` the default should be striped instead of linear. You should also take a look at `use_linear_target`.

Comment: Ah great, thanks Andreas for that. This is supported starting with LVM2 2.02.162 (2016-07-28), so I cannot use it yet, but update is planned, anyway. Unless somebody has a tip which is more directly applicable I will accept the answer.

Comment: Hmm, Ubuntu Zesty knows the option but it does not help. But I see one can specify metadata/profile information for the VG, maybe that will help...